# topology ( homework questions)

Tags: general-topology

> 1. Consider  the map $f\colon(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)\to (\mathbb{R},J)$  given  by $f(x,y)=x+y$, where  $\tau$ is  the  standard  topology  on  $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $J$  is  the  order  topology  on $\mathbb{R}$. Find  and  sketch on  the  same  plane:
>
>    - (a) The  image  of $\{0\}$ under inverse  of  $f$.
>    - (b) The  image  of $[0,1)$ under  inverse  of  $f$.
>    - (c) Is  $f$ continuous? Why?
> 2. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, define a map $d\colon\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $d(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$ where $x=(x_1,x_2)$, $y=(y_1,y_2)$.
>
>    - (a) Show that $d$ is a metric  on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
>    - (b) Find  the  basis for the  topology on  $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced  by  $d$.
>    - (c) How is the  topology induced  by $d$  related to the standard  topology on  $\mathbb{R}^2$?
> 3. Let  $S$  denote  the  unit  circle $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$, considered as a subspace  of the  plane $\mathbb{R}^2$,  and  let $f\colon [0,1)\to S$  be the  map  defined  $by f(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$.  Show that  $f$  is  continuous but not a homeomorphism.
> 4. Show  that the  function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined  by $f(x)=3x+1$ is  a  homeomorphism.

**My attempt.**

*Question 1.* (a) $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid f(x,y)=0\} = \{\text{all points in the line } x=-y\}$.

*Question 2.* (a)  $d(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|=|y_1-x_1|+|y_2-x_2|=d(y,x)$
$$\begin{align*}
d(x,y)&=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|=|x_1-z_1 + z_1-y_1|+|x_2-z_2 +z_2-y_2|\\
                      &\leq |x_1-z_1|+|x_2-z_2|+|z_1-y_1|+|z_2-y_2|\\
                      &\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)
\end{align*}$$
therefore $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

*Question 4.* $f(1)=4$, $f(2)=7$ so  $f$  is  one  to  one  hence bijection, 
I  think $f$  carries a  basis  element  from  $\mathbb{R}$ to  $\mathbb{R}$ and  vice versa, hence  $f$  is  automatically  homeomorphism

I  wish  to  know the correctness of  my  attempt , and how  I  can  attempt Question 1(b),(c); Question 2(b),(c); and Question 3.

Comment: You can use latex (between dollar signs) on this site to format your question. It will become more readable for everybody, and you will get better answers.

Comment: Did you prove that on $\mathbb R$ the order topology coincides with the standard topology?

Comment: no  i didnt  check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer 1b very similarly to how you answered 1a.  For 1c, refer to the definition of continuity.

For 2a, don't forget to show that the metric is positive-definite!  For 2b and 2c, you need to think about which sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are open in the new topology.

For Q4, you should prove your claim that "$f$ carries a basis element from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$."  By "vice-versa," do you mean that $f^{-1}$ also carries basis elements to basis elements?  You need to prove that, too.  I think your argument works, but you should double-check your definition of homeomorphism again.  The key is that $f^{-1}$ carries base sets to base sets; if you're going to examine $f$ and $f^{-1}$, it might not matter much, but you should double-check anyway.

Q3, as you've written it, doesn't make sense; do you mean "show that $f$ is continuous but not a homeomorph*ism*"?  Just show that $f$ satisfies the definition from Q4.

Comment: its to  show  that f is not homeomorphism!, i  have  no  idea

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, "show that $f$ DOESN'T satisfy the definition from Q4"!